# Unable to open hyperlinked file Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, hyperlink, apache-poi

My hyperlinked files reside in Whois dir and both dir and the Excel file are in the same parent directory. I am unable to access my files through Hyperlinks because of relative paths. I need to send this Excel file to several recipients without any change to their options. I have tried getPath(), getCanonicalPath() and getAbsolutePath() to no avail. Here is my code:

```
public void writeTheFile() throws Exception {
    int rowNum=-1;
    String line = "";

    XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.createSheet("Contact & Whois");
    XSSFCreationHelper helper = workBook.getCreationHelper();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(INPUT_FILE));

    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        rowNum++;
        XSSFRow currentRow=sheet.createRow(rowNum);
        currentRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(line.trim());
        currentRow.createCell(1);
        XSSFHyperlink file_link_downloads = helper.createHyperlink(Hyperlink.LINK_FILE);
        Cell cell = sheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(1);
        try {
            File f = new File("Whois/" + line + ".whois.txt");
            if(f.exists()) {
                cell.setCellValue("[Whois]");
                String path = f.getPath();
                file_link_downloads.setAddress(path);
                cell.setHyperlink((org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Hyperlink) file_link_downloads);
            } else {
                cell.setCellValue("-NA-");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error in setting up download link");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

On windows path is being persisted on another computer verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

Excel sets relative link from current file location. So, you have to check file existence and then set relative path.

Example:

```
Hyperlink hyperlink = creationHelper.createHyperlink(Hyperlink.LINK_FILE);
String relativePath = "../parentdir/fileToLink.txt";
hyperlink.setAddress(relativePath);
hyperlink.setLabel("Link to file");
cell.setHyperlink(hyperlink);
cell.setCellValue("Link to file");
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
```

If excel file in the same directory with linked files, just specify link as `hyperlink.setAddress("fileToLink.txt")`.

Comment: In my case the cases and the java file are both in the same folder.... Both the Whois dir and XLSX file are in the same directory ..how do I specify the relative path.

Comment: @MallikKumar I've changed answer, please have a look

Comment: lets say I have a folder called parent... parent contains both Whois and Excel file.  The Excel file links into Whois folder for fileToLink.txt. What would the relative address be?

Comment: @MallikKumar If excel file on the same level as `Whois` directory, then relative path will be `Whois/fileToLink.txt`

Comment: that is exactly what I have tried in my code....
File f = new File("Whois/" + line + ".whois.txt");

Comment: @MallikKumar Have you tried my code? for your case it would be `hyperlink.setAddress("Whois/fileToLink.txt");`

Comment: There are 370 files  in Whois. What would you have me do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98593/discussion-between-dlopatin-and-mallik-kumar).